# Reacting on cancellation in BackgroundService from outside

Tags: c#, .net-core, background-service

If I start the following example in .NET Core BackgroundService on debug mode:

```cs
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(30000, stoppingToken))
            .Wait(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

the `Ctrl + C` cancellation event does not call the `StopAsync()` Method which is calling the `Cancel()` from the `CancellationTokenSource`.

I think my problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404607/dotnet-core-iwebhost-with-backgroundservice-keeps-running-after-ctrlc) post.

How can I catch those cancellations when I'm using blocking methods inside the ExecuteAsync?

p.s.: In the real world my ExecuteAsync is watching the filesystem until a new file is created in my destination. To achieve this behavior I'm using the [FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.waitforchanged?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: `when I'm using blocking methods inside the ExecuteAsync` don't use blocking methods. Definitely don't use `Thread.Sleep` for any reason. That just wastes a threadpool thread. Use `await Task.Delay(stoppingToken)` instead

Comment: Do not mix threads and tasks

Comment: Why did you use that line anyway? You start a task that gets blocked immediatelly, then you block the original task with `Wait()`. Was that an attempt to "cancel" the `Thread.Sleep` operation?

Comment: You **also** shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In the real world I'm trying to use the FileSystemWatcher's `WaitForChanged` method to "fall asleep" until a change is incoming in the filesystem. 

@PavelAnikhouski & @Liam Thanks for your advices. This is just an example code. I'm going to update the post.

Comment: @Christopher put that in your question then. You don't need a thread with FSW either, you only need to handle events as fast as possible, preferably by quickly posting them to a queue. You can use [CancellationToken.Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-5.0) to stop the FSW when the cancellation token is triggered

Comment: @Christopher please edit the question and add the real code. This has little to do with threads, `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Delay`. Post the FSW processing code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My FSW blocking method has nothing to do with the cancellation of a blocking method. You can use any method in there which is blocking. Maybe `Task.Delay()` is a bad example?

Comment: @Christopher your question is about FWS, not `Task.Delay`, so any example that doesn't include that class isn't helping. You don't need to block calling `WaitForChanged`, you can use events. Once you do that, you don't need `Task.Run` or `Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it looks like the problem has little to do with threads. The real problem is how to stop a FileSystemWatcher.

You don't need an extra thread with a FileSystemWatcher, you need to handle its change events as quickly as possible. You can use an asynchronous event handler for this, or even better, quickly post events to a queue or Channel for processing.

To stop the FSW you can use the [CancellationToken.Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-5.0) method to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `false` :

```
stoppingToken.Register(()=>watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=false);
```

**Event processing**

To quickly handle events, one could post the [FileSystemEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs?view=net-5.0) values directly to a queue or a [Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) and process them with another tasks. This has two benefits:

- File events are handled as fast as possible, so none is lost
- The code can either wait for all events to finish, or cancel them.

```
var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<FileSystemEventArgs>();

stoppingToken.Register(()=>{
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
    channel.Writer.TryComplete();
});

watcher.Changed+=(o,e)=>channel.Writer.WriteAsync(e,stoppingToken);

await foreach(var e in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
{
    //do something
}
```

A Channel can be treated as a queue with asynchronous read and write operation. The [ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=net-5.0) method dequeues messages until stopped and returns them as an [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8) which allows the use of `await foreach` to easily handle items asynchronously.

**Pipelines and Channels**

The code can be refactored into this:

```
await watcher.AsChannel(stoppingToken)
             .ProcessEvents(stoppingToken);
```

**The consumer**

It's easy to extract the subscriber code into a separate method. This could even be an extension method:

```
public static async Task ProcessEvents(this ChannelReader<FileSystemEventArgs> reader,CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await foreach(var e in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

And call it :

```
var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<FileSystemEventArgs>();

stoppingToken.Register(()=>{
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
    channel.Writer.TryComplete();
});

watcher.Changed+=(o,e)=>channel.Writer.WriteAsync(e,stoppingToken);

await ProcessEvents(channel,stoppingToken);
```

This works because a `Channel` has [implicit cast operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2.op_implicit?view=net-5.0) to `ChannelReader` and `ChannelWriter`.

A ChannelReader supports multiple consumers, so one could use multiple tasks to process events, eg :

```
public static async Task ProcessEvents(this ChannelReader<FileSystemEventArgs> reader,int dop,CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,dop).Select(()=>{
        await foreach(var e in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            //do something
        }
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

**The producer**

It's also possible to extract the channel creation and posting into a separate method. After all, we only need the ChannelReader for processing:

```
public static ChannelReader AsChannel(this FileSystemWatcher watcher, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<FileSystemEventArgs>();

    stoppingToken.Register(()=>{
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
        channel.Writer.TryComplete();
    });

    watcher.Changed+=(o,e)=>channel.Writer.WriteAsync(e,stoppingToken);
    return channel;
}
```

And combine everything in a simple pipeline:

```
await watcher.AsChannel(stoppingToken)
             .ProcessEvents(stoppingToken);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's something I can work with. I have written a library method with FSW `WaitForChanged` method. This method is blocking until a change is registered. I've tested to cancel my method with a CancellationToken and this is working fine.

Comment: @Christopher I just posted how to handle the events without having to block, using channels

Answer (score 0):

My first workaround at the moment is this:

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var blockingTask = Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(30000, stoppingToken));
        await Task.WhenAny(blockingTask);
    }
}
```

**@Panagiotis Kanavos** I appreciate your efforts, I'm coming back to your detailed post If I'm trying to change my "blocking" FSW to an event driven FSW.

In productive I'm using something like this:

```
private void DoServiceWork() 
{ 
    // Some Work if new PDF or docx file is available 
    // ...
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    int myTimeout = 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        pdfWatchingTask = Task.Run(() => MyFSWLibrary.Watch(directory, "*.pdf", myTimeout, stoppingToken));
        docWatchingTask = Task.Run(() => MyFSWLibrary.Watch(directory, "*.docx", myTimeout, stoppingToken));

        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(new Task<MyFSWResult>[] { waitPdfTask, waitXmpTask });
        if(finishedTask.Result.Success) DoServiceWork();
    }
}
```